# samba is not working (can't connect)

Tags: server, samba, client

I want to have a shared folder using Samba and this folder should be protected by an username-password combination (kind of usual actually). What I've done so far:

1. Installed samba (was already installed)
2. useradd -m -g users sambauser
3. passwd sambauser
4. smbpasswd -a sambauser

My configuration file:

```
    [global]

 workgroup = WORKGROUP
 security = share
 share modes = yes

 [homes]
 comment = Home Directories
 browsable = no
 read only = no
 create mode = 0750

 [JanGrimm]
 path = /media/JanGrimm
 public = no
 writable = yes
 comment = Jan
 printable = no
 valid users = sambauser
```

JanGrimm is the shared folder in media, so the path of my shared folder is /media/JanGrimm

So, I've restarted the samba service and then tried to map the network drive under Windows (10):

[image]

Prompting for credentials:

[image]

Connecting now:

[image]

After some time, it prompts me again:

[image]

It obviously doesn't matter what I am entering, it is just not working. For my tries, I disabled the firewall of the server. What is wrong with that? I just can't get around..

Comment: Next time post links to the images either in your post, or in the comments and someone will edit them in. *Or* you could edit a few posts around here that need improving (formatting, grammar, etc) and get a few more reputation points and then just do it yourself ;)

Comment: add these three line in configuration file  : `wins support = yes`
`local master = yes`
`preferred master = yes`  then restart samba service `sudo service smbd restart`  then try to access.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it's still not working. After it prompted me the second time, it threw this error: http://i.imgur.com/yq1Etwt.png ... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows10 and we are using the following working samba config

```
[global]

   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   netbios name = FileServer
   wins support = yes
   dns proxy = no

   name resolve order = lmhots host wins bcast

   interfaces = 192.168.0.1/24 eth0
   bind interfaces only = yes


   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000

   syslog = 0

   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes

   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user

   usershare allow guests = yes

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[MY_SHARE]
    writeable = yes
    path = <your/File/Path>
    comment = Fileserver
    guest account = <validUser>
    wide links = no
    security = user
```

Maybe it helps you finding a solution. Note that especially in the global section your config seems very short to me

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange in Windows 10: if you use the same userid/password on your windows machine as on the samba server, actually, you do not need to provide a password.
For instance, if your are known in Windows as 'userw' with password 'xyz' and defined exactly the same user and password in samba, when your are prompted for userid/passwd on Windows 10, just enter the userid **without entering any password**.  That will do the trick.

Note that if you enter a password even the correct one, the connection will fail.

Also make sure that the domain you connect to is 'WORKGROUP', as per your config file.